# Fail to import sonata-project/form-extensions datepicker js when server base url is not "/"

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

## Context

I have a symfony application using sonata, and I have a prefix in my base url (the url of my admin dashboard is like `scheme://mysite.net/myprefix/admin/dashboard`).

If I use the `DatePickerType` in an admin form, I successfully load the `app.js` of the `sonata-project/form-extensions` package, but then I cannot the other js file chunks that are imported in `app.js`.

In my navigator dev tools, I can see that `app.js` tries to load the chunks from base domain, dropping my prefix (e.g. GET on `scheme://mysite.net/bundles/sonataform/696.js` for file `696.js`, instead of `scheme://mysite.net/myprefix/bundles/sonataform/696.js`).

The result is that I have 404 errors trying to load theses assets file, and that the datepicker does not work.

## What I already tried

I tried to build assets with a relative path on webpack (inspired by this PR: https://github.net/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/7253/files), but it did not solve my problem.

My hope was that `app.js` would load other chunks relatively to itself in my `public/bundles/sonataform` directory.

I think there should be another webpack encore configuration that would work in my situation, or maybe a package configuration option in symfony that could help ?

If so I would be gald if someone could help !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.